# Magento 2: How can I get the parent UI Element?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, uielement

I have a UI Element that has children. Is it possible for one UI Element to get the instantiated parent element?

I know there is a property called `parentName`, but that simply returns a string.

Example code:

```
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "configurator": {
                    "component": "Vendor_Module/js/configurator",
                    "template": Vendor_Module/configurator",
                    "children" : {
                        "price": {
                            "component": "Vendor_Module/js/configurator/price",
                            "template": "Vendor_Module/configurator/price",
                            "displayArea": "price",
                            "price": <?php echo $block->getPrice(); ?>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now my `js/price.js` has a `this.parentName`, but like I said, it's value is 'configurator'. How can I get the instance of the object so I can access it's properties?

I know traversing down the parent tree is bad design practice, so if anyone knows a different on how I can have multiple UI Components react with eachother, I'd be more than happy to hear them.

Comment: Can't you add the parent as a dependency in your component via Require? Unless I've misunderstood your question that would give you access to the parents object (I think?)

Comment: @BenCrook it gives me the component yes, but what I need is the instantiated component somewhere else on the page. So they can interact with eachother and I can read the variables that are set. Using it as a dependency only allows me to create a new instance.

Comment: Ah I see, I knew I misunderstood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not 100% sure it is the right way to do it and not 100% sure it will work for components as containers.

In the past I used `this.containers` variables to refer parents.

i.e.:

```
this.containers[0]
```

**Otherwise (and suggested way):**
If you need this to make children to communicate with parent you could use an external model class used as singleton and required from both parent and child.

In this way you can store common information or send/receive messages.

In the past I solved this way.

**UPDATE with Giel Berkers comment (see below):**
Another good approach could be using uiRegistry to share inforamtion between modules.

This approach is suggested when the inforamtion you need to share should be considered global.

Comment: Hm, that second approach sounds a less more like spaghetti code then using the containers-propery. I think I'll go for that approach. Thanks!

Comment: I totally agree ;) ! It is the same approach used by Magento2 itself in the checkout procedure to share totals.

Comment: When in doubt: look at how Magento does it :-). I'm going to use `uiRegistry` for this one. Seems the most logical choice to share information between objects.

Comment: If you just need to share simple information that is the best way. My suggestion was for more structured information. In Magento code you can see both approaches.

Comment: Just a style doubt: Is using uiRegistry correct if your information are not global and only used by two components?

Comment: `uiRegistry` is global by definition, just like the Magento (PHP) registries. It's the nature of the pattern. If it's only need to be used by 2 components then yes: you might write your own implementation, but then again: why re-invent the wheel when Magento offers tons of utilities under the hood to address these kind of tasks?

Comment: Eh eh eh, you are right man ;)

Comment: Check out this page: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html

Using imports, exports, links and listens you can create dependencies between ui components (also without hardcoding them in your JS)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`uiRegistry.get(this.parentName)`](https://mage2.pro/t/5484) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also require your specific class through the definition array in your class where you need the parent.

I had the same problem: I can`t get the parent in a child. After some research I came up with this idea:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/validation',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Your_Module/js/view/listing/form'
], function ($, Component, ko, $t, validation, registry, form) {
    'use strict';

return Component.extend({

[...]
```

Where `'Your_Module/js/view/listing/form'` is my parent which I needed.
Later in the extended Object I can then use the `form` object to access the parent instance by using it as a function call:

```
form().anyMethod()
```